# Are there alternatives to nicefrac that does not shrink numerator and denominator

Tags: math-mode

I want a fraction like nicefrac, but with normal size denominator and numerator. Is there a package for that?

Comment: Have a look at the package `xfrac`.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: xfrac shrinks numerator and denominator as well.

Comment: What would be the use of these?

Comment: @egreg Er, fractional powers (used all the time in mathematics).

Comment: @User17670 Sorry, but I've been into maths for 30+ years and I have never seen fractions à la `nicefrac`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a definition that does not shrink either and that you can modify to your taste:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\begin{document}
\def\nicefrac#1#2{%
    \raise.5ex\hbox{#1}%
    \kern-.1em/\kern-.15em%
    \lower.25ex\hbox{#2}}


Here is a nice fraction: $\nicefrac{3}{5}$.        
\end{document}
```

Comment: What I was looking for! I slightly modified your definition of `\nicefrac ` to read `\def\nicefrac#1#2{
    \raise.5ex\hbox{$#1$}%
    \kern-.1em/\kern-.15em%
    \lower.25ex\hbox{$#2$}}`. This allows for instance for `$\nicefrac{\partial f}{\partial x}$`.