# I think fractional expressions in my text is small and not normal?

Tags: math-mode, xetex, amsmath

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}  
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts}  
\usepackage{xepersian}  

\begin{document}  
\begin{persian}  
\lr{$-\frac{1}{3}$}  
\hspace{1cm}  
$-\frac{1}{3}$   
\hspace{1cm}   
\lr{1}  
\end{persian}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: You're using single dollar signs, so the mathematics is typeset in 'inline maths' mode, so the maths fits on a text line. If you want displayed maths, try `\[ ... \]`.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52802/3083 -- Alternatives for Nicefrac.

Answer (score 1):

If you want display-style (i.e., "large") fractions in inline or text-style math mode, as is the case in your MWE, use the macro `\dfrac` instead of `\frac`.

The macros `\dfrac` ("display-style \frac") and `\tfrac` ("text-style \frac") are provided by the `amsmath` package (which is loaded in your MWE).

Comment: @Mico.Thank you.also I have this problem in exponential Formula?

Comment: @user50054 - could you be a bit more specific about which exponential formula you have in mind? (I can think of a lot of formulas that involve exponential terms...)

Comment: @Mico probably y=e^x should do

Comment: @subhamsoni - I was wondering if the OP had something like `$e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}$` in mind.

Answer (score 1):

If you want type fractions at normal size inline text, add `\displaystyle` between `$ $` and before `\frac`, or use `\dfrac` (from `amsmath` package):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts}  
\usepackage{xepersian}  
\begin{document}  
\begin{persian}  
\lr{$\displaystyle-\frac{1}{3}$}  
\hspace{1cm}  
$-\dfrac{1}{3}$   
\hspace{1cm}   
\lr{1}  
\end{persian}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: The instruction `\displaystyle` affects *all* material until the end of the current inline math environment, and not just the appearance of `\frac`. This matters if the OP might wish to create larger fractions but not large sum and integral symbols as well.

Answer (score 0):

If `\dfrac` is too large, you also can have  `medium-sized` maths with the `nccmath` package; in particular it defines an `\mfrac` command. Medium-sized maths are about 80 % if `\displaystyle` and most usually don't produce unequal interline spacing if you slightly increase `\baselinestretch`, e.g. `setstretch{1.08}` (it's the recommended way of doing; the command is defined in the  `setspace` package.

You have a `medsize` and an `mmmatrix` environments, and a number of other medsize commands.
An example for the fractions:

\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{fourier}
    \usepackage{heuristica}

```
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}

\begin{document}

Here’s an \verb+align+ environment typeset first with \verb+\tfrac+, then \verb+\mfrac+, and finally \verb+\dfrac+:
\begin{align*}
      \rightarrow \quad &x=3, \tfrac{10}{3},\tfrac{11}{3}. \\
      \rightarrow \quad &x=3, \mfrac{10}{3},\mfrac{11}{3}. \\
      \rightarrow \quad &x=3, \frac{10}{3},\frac{11}{3}. \\
\end{align*}

This is a text in paragraph typeset with \verb+\tfrac+: $\textrm{C.S}=\{3,\frac{10}{3},\frac{11}{3}\}$.

This is a text in another paragraph typeset with \verb+\mfrac+: $\textrm{C.S}=\Bigl\{3,\mfrac{10}{3},\mfrac{11}{3}\Bigr\}$.

And finally a paragraph typeset with \verb+\dfrac+: $\textrm{C.S}=\biggl\{3,\dfrac{10}{3},\dfrac{11}{3}\biggr\}$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

It appears that `nccmath` may have some problems if used in a minipage environment, though I never had personally. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22102/nccmath-affecting-minipage-widths) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22167/minipage-content-overlaps-with-text-before-that-if-nccmath-is-used). In case of problem, what could hopefully be a solution is sketched in the comments.